# I'm not understanding what "Version" v I have to put as a format of date

Tags: python, foursquare

I'm using the FOURSQUARE API for extracting the venue searches. I have created a URL with my client_id and client_secret. But I'm unable to know what VERSION DATE I need to put.

[image]

Please check the error in the image. I checked online but can't quite understand it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### First of All:

Go **revoke and regenerate your token immediately**, since you just posted it to the internet

Your URL only contained 3 format variables (count the `{}` characters in your format string)

You tried to stuff 4 variables into a format string containing 3 holes.

```
.format(
    venue_id, # gets placed in the url after client_id=
    CLIENT_ID,  # gets placed after client_secret=
    CLIENT_SECRET, # placed after v=
    VERSION  # placed nowhere because you don't have a 4th {} in the string.
)
```

The error result you are seeing shows your CLIENT_SECRET is an invalid version.

You may be violating their TOS by publishing your client keys, that is why you should revoke and regenerate.

### Suggestion

#### use named format strings

if you used named strings, then you will reduce your chance to make mistakes like this because if a required name isn't passed in you'll get an error, if you pass in extra, no problem, but you won't get this config shifting error.

```
url = "https://<stuff>/client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&v={version}".format(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    version=VERSION
)
```

or shorthand format strings where the variables inside the format string are named variables in your program.

```
url = f"https://<stuff>/client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}&v={VERSION}"
#     ^
#-----| # f indicates this is an inline format string
```